# How to get android 2.3.4 sourcecode?

Tags: android

Exactly the android 2.3.4's sourcecode. Anyone can help me?

I have got the android2.3.3's sourcecode,any one know how to update it to 2.3.4?

I don't want to download the whole sourcecode. - -

Comment: Thank you for answering. Do you know how to update android2.3.3's sourcecode to 2.3.4?

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html), pretty much.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Do you know how to update android2.3.3's sourcecode to 2.3.4?

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/manifest.git;a=tag;h=89b8af0fd7287b053caf80ac10e285a486c44a78) the tag for Android 2.3.4 release 1.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Do you know how to update android2.3.3's sourcecode to 2.3.4?

Comment: Thank you for answering. Do you know how to update android2.3.3's sourcecode to 2.3.4?

Comment: If you download the source now, you'll get 2.3.5.